# REST Api for O365 EO Recoverable items folder

Tags: python, outlook, exchangewebservices

I want to fetch events from **Recoverable** items folder inside **Deleted** Items.

Do we have support with rest API to access these mails/calendars/contacts inside recoverable folder?

I couldn't find any article about it nor it is listed in outlook mail rest API reference.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can use the WellKnownFolder enumerations for the RecoverableItems folders so make a request like this to list all the folders

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('user@domain.com')/MailFolders/recoverableitemsroot/childfolders/?$Top=1000
```

or for items in the folders

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('user@domain.com')/MailFolders/recoverableitemsdeletions/messages
```

Comment: I am able to fetch deleted mails from recoverable items using using https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/MailFolders/RecoverableItemsDeletions/messages and deleted contacts using https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/contactfolders/RecoverableItemsDeletions/contacts .
But I am not able to fetch calendar deleted events. How to fetch deleted events?

Comment: Its a current limitation of that endpoint you can only get items that have an Item Class (or subclass) of IPM.Note