# How to retrieve EVERY mail message (including Deleted, Archived, and Recoverable items) for an O365 user with Graph API?

Tags: outlook, office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api, outlook-restapi

We are working on an application in the compliance/monitoring space where we are monitoring the activity of an individual. Because of this, we want to pull EVERYTHING in a user's Office 365 mailbox - if it has text the user wrote or received, we want it if it is there, even if it was deleted, purged, etc.

We are using the Graph API and have an existing implementation that uses the standard "messages" GET command:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages
```

We are making use of the GraphApiClient (Microsoft.Graph v1.9.0), so the code actually looks like this:

```
IUserMessagesCollectionPage pageOfMessages = _graphClient.Users[userId].Messages.Request(options).Top(batchSize).Expand("attachments").GetAsync().Result;
```

However, at the very least this does not return any items from any of the RecoverableItems folders. After looking into it, I am now suspicious that there might be other folders that are not returned by this command either. There is quite the list of [Well-known folder names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/mailfolder?view=graph-rest-1.0) and I'm not sure what others might not be included in a generic Messages request.

Based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52424767/rest-api-for-o365-eo-recoverable-items-folder), I know you can request the messages in the missing folders by WellKnownFolderName one at a time like this:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/MailFolders/RecoverableItemsDeletions/messages
```

It even works with the GraphApiClient:

```
IMailFolderMessagesCollectionPage pageOfMessages = _graphClient.Users[userId].MailFolders["RecoverableItemsDeletions"].Messages.Request(options).Top(batchSize).Expand("attachments").GetAsync().Result;
```

The problems with this are:

1. I don't know how to build a comprehensive list of every folder that has messages for the user
2. Some of the folders (like RecoverableItemsDeletions and ArchiveRecoverableItemsDeletions, for example) can contain duplicates so I would need to use a dictionary to get rid of the duplicates
3. It would be a lot more expensive to first build a list of relevant folders and then request their contents and their childrens' contents one request at a time.
4. At scale, a folder-by-folder implementation could be subject to  [throttling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling) (if we are monitoring enough users with big enough mailboxes)

Does anyone know the best way to do this? Thanks!